# Sort data of a column in a grid obtained by PyGridTableBase

Tags: wxpython

I extract the data from sqlite file and then add it to the grid using PyGridTableBase of wxpython 1000 cells at a time. Here I would like to sort entire column data. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the wxPython Demo package. Then look up the Grid_MegaExample. It shows how to sort columns using a right-click menu. At least, that's what this answer said: [Sorting on on columns in wxpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581525/sorting-on-on-columns-in-wxpython)

I just tested it on my machine and it works fine. I have Python 2.6.6, wxPython 2.8.12, Windows 7.